# Is a space of polynomials over Real numbers complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, complete-spaces

Let $P$ be the space of all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ normed by, $\|P\|= \max \{|a_0|,|a_1|,|a_2|,...,|a_n|\}$ where $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$. Is this space complete?

Actually this problem is regarding the open mapping theorem. The map from $p$ to $p$ is not open. But this map isn't contradict the open mapping theorem. I thought its because, $P$ is not a Banach space.

Comment: Hi @Miraj Chamara, welcome to MSE. Did you already try to prove this? It's no problem if you make any mistakes, but we can help you more if you try first.

Comment: yes. I have tried this. Actually this problem is regarding the open mapping theorem. The map from p to p is not open. But this map isn't contradict the open mapping theorem. I thought its because, P is not a Banach space.

Comment: It is not complete in any norm, by Baire's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \frac {x^{k}} {k!}$ is a Cauchy sequence which does not converge.